# jQuery UI - On Select Change The Date Format Of The Input Box

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am using something to prevent a user from selecting certain dates.

I have created the following jQuery :

```
var str = "2014-02-15,2014-04-03,2014-04-05,1970-01-01";
var array = str.split(",");

$('.select_date_start, .select_date_end').datepicker(
{
 beforeShowDay: function(date)
  {
     var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
     return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
  }
```

When the user selects a date, It is returning it back as : "04/02/2014" I need it to be in yy-mm-dd format.

How can I do this so that when they select a date, It inputs in the back as the format of yy-mm-dd?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use dateformat option in jquery-ui

```
 var str = "2014-02-15,2014-04-03,2014-04-05,1970-01-01";
 var array = str.split(",");
     $( '.select_date_start, .select_date_end').datepicker({
      beforeShowDay: function(date)
      {
       var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
       },
      dateFormat:"yy-mm-dd"

       });
```